# IndexError in Django. List out of range

Tags: python, django

I have a program that takes in input from user then splits the values and converts it into a list.

```
num_of_subjects = 5 #input by user
subjects = ['eng', 'maths', 'sci', 'his'] #wrong input by user
```

expecting

```
subjects = ['eng', 'maths', 'sci', 'his', 'phy'] #because num_of_subjects is 5
```

views.py

```
def schoolinput_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    subjects_view = request.POST.get('subjects')

   for i in range(num_of_subjects):
       sub = subjects_view[i]
       print(sub)
```

This gives an list out of range error as expected so I tried

```
try:
    def schoolinput_view(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        subjects_view = request.POST.get('subjects')

    for i in range(num_of_subjects):
       sub = subjects_view[i]
       print(sub)
except IndexError as listerror:
    print('Please check if subjects meet number of subjects')
```

And this didn't solve the problem and still gives IndexError even if the exception is handled.

Comment: the try-except needs to be inside your function...

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead is before continuing to the next process, to verify that the number of subjects they entered matches.

```
if num_of_subjects == len(subjects):
    for i in range(num_of_subjects):
        sub = subjects_view[i]
        print(sub)
else:
    print('Please check if subjects meet number of subjects')
```

You can also shorten

```
for i in range(num_of_subjects):
    sub = subjects_view[i]
    print(sub)
```

to

```
for subject in subjects:
    print(subject)
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem as the the post request is made on a button click which processes everything and verifying won't do anything to it.

Comment: @codekls Try putting the try/except inside of the def function